# Alternative to nsjail and firejail on Windows

Tags: windows, sandbox

I wrote a little platform-OS independent webservice, which accesses certain user files, depending on who is logged in.

On Linux I found [njsail](https://github.com/google/nsjail) or [firejail](https://firejail.wordpress.com/) which help with process isolations. That means, once a logged-in user starts a process in the incoming connection to read out the data, it is wrapped in such sandbox commands to ensure he can't break out of his "user-directory".

Is there a similar solution available on Windows as well?

Comment: you can look at the below site link for all other available alternative : [https://alternativeto.net/software/firejail/?platform=windows](https://alternativeto.net/software/firejail/?platform=windows)

Answer (score 1):

[Sandboxie](https://sandboxie-plus.com/Sandboxie/) would be your best bet it was developed by Sophos and passed down. Windows is a "OK" platform but remember it is not as security/privacy focused so this is the only software I can think of at this time.